# IOKit crash - ' malloc ... Invalid pointer dequeued from free list'

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, serial-port, iokit

First : what I am trying to do is find devices connected to a mac the same way calling

```
ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*
```

in Terminal does
but by using IOKit

Second, here is my code :

```
@IBAction func testPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var portIterator: io_iterator_t = 0
        let kernResult = findSerialDevices(kIOSerialBSDModemType, serialPortIterator: &portIterator)
        if kernResult == KERN_SUCCESS {
            printSerialPaths(portIterator)
        }

    }

func findSerialDevices(deviceType: String, inout serialPortIterator: io_iterator_t ) -> kern_return_t {
        var result: kern_return_t = KERN_FAILURE
        var classesToMatch = IOServiceMatching(kIOSerialBSDServiceValue).takeUnretainedValue()
        var classesToMatchDict = (classesToMatch as NSDictionary) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        classesToMatchDict[kIOSerialBSDTypeKey] = deviceType
        let classesToMatchCFDictRef = (classesToMatchDict as NSDictionary) as CFDictionaryRef
        result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, classesToMatchCFDictRef, &serialPortIterator);
        return result
    }

    func printSerialPaths(portIterator: io_iterator_t) {
        var serialService: io_object_t
        do {
            serialService = IOIteratorNext(portIterator)
            if (serialService != 0) {
                let key: CFString! = "IOCalloutDevice"
                let bsdPathAsCFtring: AnyObject? = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(serialService, key, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue()
                var bsdPath = bsdPathAsCFtring as String?
                if let path = bsdPath {
                    println(path)
                }
            }
        } while serialService != 0;
    }
```

When I run this in a command line tool (new project > os x > command line tool) it works well. (I basically write the same code only the four lines in the 'testPressed' function are not in an IBAction)

console output :

```
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem
/dev/cu.usbmodem1411
```

When I run it from a cocoa mac application, it crashes after correctly executing the code :

```
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem
/dev/cu.usbmodem1411
serialTests(40925,0x7fff77354300) malloc: *** error for object 0x61000003243c: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(lldb)
```

I've researched this, googled the error, read the IOKit fundamentals app developer's guide, re-wrote the code in a  separate project to make sure there wasn't something wrong in the other project I didn't notice.
And I still can't fix the bug

Comment: have you solved the problem... I am dealing with the same exact code.

Comment: @KorayBirand:  Yes and no... I was building an in-house testing app to communicate with a device we make via USB. I gave up on IOKit, and used ORSSerialPort instead (a third party library). That made it MUCH easier. Let me know if I can help with that

Comment: Exactly what I did :)))